# VScodeで作ったCSVファイルをnumbersで開くと白紙の状態になる。

Tags: python, vscode, csv, pycharm

#### 前提・実現したいこと

VScodeで作ったCSVファイルをnumbersで開くと白紙の状態になるので解決したい。

VScodeで作ったCSVファイルを作成する所まではできたのですが、作ったファイルをデスクトップに移動させ、numbersで開くと白紙の状態となってしまいます。

※PyCharmにて作成し、デスクトップに移動さした後numbersで開いた画像⬇︎
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

※VScodeにて作成し、デスクトップに移動さした後numbersで開いた画像⬇︎
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 該当のソースコード

```
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint



chrome_path = '/Users/nakamotokenta/Desktop/ScrapingBeginner-main/chromedriver'

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--incognito')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path,options=options)

url = 'https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image'
driver.get(url)

sleep(3)

query = 'ねこ'
search_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('SearchBox__searchInput')
search_box.send_keys(query)
search_box.submit()

sleep(3)

height = 50
while height < 150:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(height))
    height += 100
    print(height)

    sleep(1)

#画像の要素を選択する
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sw-Thumbnail')

print(len(elements))

d_list = []
#要素からURLを取得する
for i, element in enumerate(elements, start=1):
    name = f'{query}_{i}'
    raw_url = element.find_element_by_class_name('sw-ThumbnailGrid__details').get_attribute('href')
    yahoo_image_url = element.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src')
    title = element.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('alt')

    d = {
        'filename': name,
        'raw_url': raw_url,
        'yahoo_image_url': yahoo_image_url,
        'title': title
    }

    d_list.append(d)

    sleep(2)

    print('finished {}'.format(name))

pprint(d_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(d_list)
print(df.head())
print(df.shape)
df.to_csv('image_url_20210823.csv')

driver.quit()
```

#### 試したこと

VScodeと同じコードをPyCharmで実行し、デスクトップに移動させ、numbersで開くと白紙ではなく表が作成されています。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

macOS Big Sur ver11.5
numbers バージョン 11.1

**エディタ**
①PyCharm 2021.2 (Community Edition)
python 3.9

②VScode バージョン: 1.59.1
python 3.8.8 64-bit ('base':conda)

※追記
マルチポストが推奨されていないことを知らず、早く解決できるかもと思い、他のサービスにも質問投稿してしまいました。
⬇︎がそのサイトです
[https://teratail.com/questions/355847]

※追記2（それぞれのファイルの先頭256バイト程度をダンプ表示）
●PyCharmで作成したCSVファイルです⬇︎
「2C66696C 656E616D 652C7261 775F7572 6C2C7961 686F6F5F 696D6167 655F7572 6C2C7469 746C650A 302CE381 ADE38193 5F312C68 74747073 3A2F2F74 6F796F6B 65697A61 692E6E65 742F6172 7469636C 65732F2D 2F333337 3435342C 68747470 733A2F2F 6D73702E 632E7969 6D672E6A 702F696D 61676573 2F76322F 46555469 39337458 71343035 67725A56 47674471 477A6762 7273786D 705A6D56 5A544345 64723931 6276464A 666C5757 3359657A 4A365353 59617971 306E5048 66773337 76425777 776E2D32 616C6746 4A354C6B 344C3147 49776354 426A5A79 5544496B 37552D58 7466754D 58684534 456C3151 6A4A5339 65625477 56477A32 5F314A73」

●VScodeで作成したCSVファイルです⬇︎
「」
こちらは何も表示されませんでした。

※追記3
VScodeにて作ったファイルをFinderから探し、Finderでダブルクリックするとnumbersで作成した表を表示することができました！（PyCharmでデスクトップにドラック&ドロップした時の表と同じものができた！）
VSccodeでドラック&ドロップした時のみ白紙のCSVファイルになっている状態です。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/355847) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 白紙状態というのは分かりませんが、良くありそうなのがエンコーディングや改行コードが違うことでは？ `.to_csv`で書き出す時のオプションを明示していくつかのパターンを試してみては？ [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) 他に直接ではないけれど関連しそうな記事 [CSVファイルをNumbersで開くと文字化けする問題を解決する方法](https://bamka.info/numbers-csv), [マックでNumbersでファイル作成しました。](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14182383064), [CSVファイルが文字化けした場合の対処方法](https://support.freee.co.jp/hc/ja/articles/115002727126)

Comment: cubickさんご指摘ありがとうございます。マルチポストが推奨されていないことを知らず他のサイトでも投稿してしまいました。問題が解決次第、両サイトにて報告と解決方法の投稿を行います。

Comment: @kunifさん回答ありがとうございます！調べてみます！

Comment: `PyCharm`や`VSCode`はIDEやエディタ(を拡張した開発環境)であって、それでCSVファイルそのものを作ったわけでは無く、CSVファイルはそれらで作成したPythonスクリプト(SeleniumでのWebスクレイピング)を実行して作った結果となるでしょう。細かいことですが自分が何を行っているのかを正しく認識していないと、問題を起こしやすく解決は遠のくことになります。その上でMacOS上ならファイルを16進ダンプ表示するツールがあるでしょうから、それぞれのCSVファイルの先頭256バイト程度をダンプ表示させて質問に追記してみてください。

Comment: @kunif さん回答ありがとうございます！確かにおっしゃられているとうりです。自分が何を行っているのか正しく認識できていません。ご指摘ありがとうございます。追記してみたのですが、ダンプ表示というものを初めて知った為、要望されているものを追記できていないかもしれません。

Comment: スクリーンショット右上に「読み込みました」と出ていないので, 新規扱いなのでは？ 保存するときに `image_url_20210823.csv` のファイル名にパス付けてはどうでしょう？ (例えばデスクトップに保存するとか)

Comment: @oriri さん回答ありがとうございます！df.to_csv('/Users/nakamotokenta/Desktop/potesara.csv')で実行するとデスクトップに保存することができました！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

**cubickさん、kunifさん、oririさん回答ありがとうございました！**
VScodeで作ったCSVファイルをnumbersで表示させる(しかもデスクトップで)という目的は達成できました！

```
df.to_csv('/Users/nakamotokenta/Desktop/potesara.csv')
```

に書き換えることでデスクトップに保存することができました！
ありがとうございました！
他のサイトで投稿したものもしっかり解決方法を投稿します！

＊今回デスクトップに保存できたものをVScodeに持っていき再度デスクトップに持ってくるとまた白紙の状態になってしまいましたが目的は達成できたのでこれでよしとさせていただきます。